# gcc dumpversion is showing different version

Tags: c, gcc

I have downloaded gcc binaries (gcc-4.8.2-16.el7.x86_64.rpm). i extracted (it created a directory usr) and checked the version of 
gcc using

```
usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc -dumpversion
```

It says it as 4.4.6. But it should have been 4.8.2. right. I tried downloading  4.8.2 rpm from different mirrors but "dumpversion" is not showing right version.

Can you please let me know the reason and also tell me how to download the 4.8.2 gcc.?

Comment: You really should install the rpm. Most packages are not designed to be run from arbitrary directories - and might contain absolute references to other files that the executable will open etc. You can't expect that extracting your rpm to an arbitrary location to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The "dumped" version number is correct, that you can be sure of.

The path that you query is very odd. Normally it should be `gcc`, `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` or something similar.¹

And GCC always has a variant with the explicit version number, so try `gcc-4.8` or `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8`.

<sup>1) But Redhat is known to invent their own rules ...</sup>

Comment: The path is inside the extracted rpm directory.not in linux filesystem.

Comment: Is it possible that you simply have downloaded an incorrectly named file from some odd source?

Comment: i tried 3 different sites.. can anyone give me the official direct link for gcc-4.8.2

Comment: **GCC 4.8.2 has major defects**, use 4.8.3 instead! [rpmfind.net](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=x86_64) gives me this package: [gcc-4.8.3-7.fc19.x86_64](http://www.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/testing/19/x86_64/gcc-4.8.3-7.fc19.x86_64.html). But why do you download RPMs manually anyway?

Comment: am making my own toolchain for my software to build it in build system. i downloaded it because my target system is centos 7 with 3.10 kernel which is using gcc 4.8.2

Comment: Maybe compiling it yourself is an option? Have a look at http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler.